# Boolean equation simplification

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

This is the problem: XY’ + XYZ + XY'Z= X + Y'Z

And so far I have this,

XY’ + XYZ + XY'Z= X + Y'Z
X(Y’ + YZ + Y’Z)    Factor out X
X(Y’ + Z + Y’Z)    De Morgan

Any tips on how to proceed? I know it shouldn't be very hard but I am stuck..

**EDITED**. How about this:

This is the problem: (AB’ + ABC)’ +A’BC’= A’ + BC’
And so far I have this,

```
  A’B + A’B’C’ + A’BC’      
  A’(B + B’C’+ BC’)  
  A’(B + (B’+B)C’)  
      ???
```

Any tips on how to proceed? I know it shouldn't be very hard but I am stuck..

Answer (score 3):

You incorrectly applied DeMorgan's (there's no need for DeMorgan's).

After factoring out $X$, you have $$\begin{align} X(Y' + YZ +Y'Z) & = X[Y' + (\underbrace{Y+Y'}_{\large =\,1})Z] \\ \\ & = X(Y' + Z)\end{align}$$

as desired.

ADDED after edited question:

You didn't apply DeMorgan's correctly in your first "move". Starting from the beginning:

$$\begin{align} (AB’ + ABC)’ +A’BC’ & = (AB')'(ABC)' + A'BC' \\ \\ 
& = (A'+B)(A'+B'+C') + A'BC' \\ \\ 
&= [A' + (B(B'+C'))] + A'BC' \\ \\
& = A' + BC' + A'BC'\\ \\
&= A' + BC'\end{align}$$

Comment: But why is X(Y' + Z) = X + Y'Z ?

Comment: @user927900 $X(Y'+Z) \neq X+Y'Z$. The original problem statement is wrong since [$XY'+XYZ+XY'Z$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28X+%26%26+not+Y%29+%7C%7C+%28X+%26%26+Y+%26%26+Z%29+%7C%7C+%28X+%26%26+not+Y+%26%26+Z%29) $\neq$ [$X+Y'Z$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=X+%7C%7C+%28not+Y+%26%26+Z%29).

Comment: @amWhy Done. Reciprocate if you see a need but don't consider that you owe me anything. :)

Comment: @amWhy I edited the question, maybe now it is in its correct form.

Comment: @JohnHabert Edited the question.

Comment: @user927900 Your edit question works as expected.